# Vim colors too bright (terminal)

Tags: vim, osx-lion, iterm, iterm2

I have a problem with Vim and iTerm2, the colors are too bright (for ALL themes). It works with both Terminal.app and MacVim, so I guess it must be some setting in iTerm2 I've completely missed.

The picture below shows you the difference (iTerm2 to the left, MacVim / Terminal.app to right):
[image]

What I'm using:

iTerm2: Build 1.0.0.20130624
Terminal type: xterm-256
Shell: zsh 5.0.2
Vim: version 7.3.666
OS X: 10.7.5

Do you guys have any idea what I'm missing?

Comment: Try changing the colors of your profile in iterm2 (Preferences -> Profiles -> (Theme name) -> Colors). Ive noticed that on some terminal emulator the defaults don't always work well

Comment: If you go into the terminal settings there is options for the adjustment of the colors.

Comment: Changing Theme or colors, in Preferences -> Profile -> Colors, only changes the colors outside of Vim, inside Vim it stays exactly the same.

Comment: What color scheme are you using?

Comment: It doesn't matter, I've tried like 20-30 of them. They are all a tad bit too bright. But in the image posted I used Kolor.

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't compare colorschemes in GUI Vim and in CLI Vim: the number of colors that can be used in both contexts is very different and it makes any comparison worthless. You can get very subtle colors in GUI Vim but you can only approximate them in CLI Vim.

The values used for the gui and those used for the cli are probably different which explains what you see.

The *only* way to have the same colors in gui and cli vim is to use only colors from the xterm palette for the gui.

In Vim, you could `:set background=light` (and read `:help 'background'`) to see if it makes the colors less bright.

In your terminal emulator, you could see if there's a setting that deals with color brightness or the usage of bold.

Comment: I thought I was very clear it wasn't a GUI / CLI issue, since it's looks like it should when using CLI Vim in Terminal.app. So I'm pretty sure it's a iTerm2 related issue.
Changing background=light/dark doesn't make any difference. There is a checkbox for bold, but only for text and it's the overall brightness that's the problem. I must be missing something simple.

Comment: I had this problem, but adding `set background=light` after `set term=xterm-256color` in my `.vimrc` file *did* in fact solve the problem for me. Passersby should try that, even if @romainl didn't quite grok all aspects of the question.

Answer (score 1):

Adding this to my vimrc *after* the colorscheme definition worked for me.

```
hi Normal ctermbg=16
```

Color codes are defined here: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Xterm256_color_names_for_console_Vim

Answer (score 0):

In case it helps anyone, iTerm2 has a setting for "Minimum Contrast" that I had enabled for better readability, but in vim it made the colors too dim.

[image]